# Check what content is equal to, if a certain string then replace with a unicode

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I was wondering how to do what my title described in js / jQuery, preferably with regex.

What I am trying to do is look for the a certain word inside a html element, in this case inside nav li a, and replace that with a unicode.

Specifically looking for the word 'GooglePlus' and replacing it with the unicode  .

How could one do this with js or jquery and regex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$("nav li a").text(function(i,currentText) {
    return currentText.replace(/GooglePlus/g, "");
});
```

When you pass a function to the [`.text()` method](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text) it will be called for each element in the jQuery object (i.e., all of your anchor elements), receiving as a parameter the current text, so then you just return that value with the appropriate replacement.